# Transform array into simple array format

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, transform

How to transform array `SVG` from this format:

**ARRAY SVG:**

```
[
  new google.maps.LatLng(12.34, 56.789),
  new google.maps.LatLng(87.65, 123.45)
]
```

to this format:

```
[
  [56.789, 12.34],
  [123.45, 87.65]
]
```

?
Is there any way?

**BIG UPDATE:**

I was try with:

```
var svg[];
function createNewArray() {
for(var i = 0; i < svg.length; i++) {
    newsvg.push(
        [newsvg[i].lng(), newsvg[i].lat()]
    );
}
    return newsvg;

}
```

but i get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'lng' of undefined
message: "Cannot call method 'lng' of undefined"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: *"Is there any way?"* I'm sure the `LatLng` have properties with which you can access the actual values for latitude and longitude. You can use those to create a new array with the desired format. If you don't know how arrays work: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html. If you want to find out more about the `LatLng` objects, have a look at the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng.

Comment: I was try with this code: function kreiranjeniza () {
for(var i = 0; i < svg.length; i++) {
    newsvg.push(
        [newsvg[i].lng(), newsvg[i].lat()]
    );
}
 return nizbaza;

}

Comment: Well, your code contains syntax errors. And `newsvg` is not defined. And btw, this doesn't have anything to do with SVG. Copy your code here http://www.jshint.com/ and you will see the errors.

Comment: well newsvg []; is created in my code above... i dont put all my code...

Comment: please show me on jsfiddle how this shoudl must look like

Comment: Ok, still `var svg[];` is a syntax error. And what's actually the problem with your function? I'd assume you want to use `svg[i].lng()` instead of `newsvg[i].lng()`.

Comment: dont return me a valid array format...

Comment: Do I really have to ask for every bit of information? What is the format of the returned array? Please update your question and include (if not present yet) (1) What you are trying to do (2) the code you are using (3) the input (4) the desired output (5) the current output (6) any other problems with your code (e.g. error messages). That would be a proper description of your problem and would give us enough clues to help you.

Comment: I try to convert SVG array in second example format

Comment: To be clear, there is no such thing as a SVG array. SVG is a XML based markup language to describe vector graphics (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG). You just have an array with two `google.maps.LatLng` objects.

Comment: And as I already suggested, since you are iterating over the `svg` array, you probably want to access `svg[i].lng()`, *not* `newsvg[i].lng()`. If `newsvg` is the new *empty* array, then of course `newsvg[i]` would return `undefined`.

Comment: so please write jsfiddle as answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are iterating over `svg`, you have to access `svg`, not `newsvg`. Use

```
svg[i].lng()
```

instead of

```
newsvg[i].lng()
```

Assuming that `newsvg` is the new, empty array, it doesn't contain any elements yet, and hence accessing the `i`th element fails.